# Apple Mach-O Linker Error when Run simulator with Facebook SDK

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook-ios-sdk

I have added Facebook SDK Framework into my Xcode 6.

Then I import it to my AppDelegate.h file.

Then I put this code   [FBLoginView class]; into this function

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

And when I clicked on Run Simulator I get this:
[image]

I'm a newbie and so confuse about what the error is. Please give me solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error usually occurs either when you don't have the correct frameworks (might be missing one) or when you don't have the right thing in linker flags.

Go to the main page for the app (on the navigation thing on the left click on your apps name or the top section) -> Build Settings  and under Linker Flags, make sure there is nothing in your Other Linker Flags.  I had this same error when I had **-ObjC** in my other Linker Flags.

Good luck